# Colour bar charts; Not sure if I am collecting the correct range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with applying a previous bit of code I have used for the same process in a different workbook.

The process is that I have conditionally formatted a set of information (now on a different sheet) to change colour based on whether either "Lab" or "Office" is selected from the drop down list.

I then wanted (what I believe this code should do however I  don't believe I have linked the series correctly) the graph which the information is in relation too to change the relevant data points to that colour, highlighting that on this floor you have selected "Office" or "Lab".

The code I am using starts here:

```
Sub CellColorsToChart()
    Dim xChart As Chart
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim xRowsOrCols As Long, xSCount As Long
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set xChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Net Internal Area").Chart.Refresh
    If xChart Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    xSCount = xChart.SeriesCollection.Count
    
    For I = 1 To xSCount
        J = 1
        With xChart.SeriesCollection(I)
            Set xRg = ActiveSheet.Range(Split(Split(.Formula, ",")(2), "!")(1))
            If xSCount > 4 Then
                xRowsOrCols = xRg.Columns.Count
            Else
                xRowsOrCols = xRg.Rows.Count
            End If
            For Each xCell In xRg
                .Points(J).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(xCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex)
                .Points(J).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(xCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex)
                J = J + 1
            Next
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Document can be downloaded here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fbdb338026e7c42cc08193536270cdfc20211115102313/07937d

Any help or tips on how to understand and read this better would be amazing.

Best
Jack

Comment: First of all you need to remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line is evil! It hides **all** your error messages but the errors still occur, you just cannot see their messages. If you don't see the messages you cannot fix your errors, if you don't fix them, your code cannot work properly. So first remove that line, see which errors you get and fix them. See [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

Comment: Thank you for your guidance and link! - I have since reviewed and no longer have any error messages however when I change the information in the drop down, to change the values in another sheet the graph still does not update. I will be spending the evening reading some information on linking the information correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Refresh` from this line `Set xChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Net Internal Area").Chart.Refresh` and refresh chart after `If xChart Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CellColorsToChart()

    Dim xChart As Chart
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, ix As Long
    Dim xSCount As Long
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    
    Set xChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Net Internal Area").Chart
    If xChart Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xChart.Refresh
    xSCount = xChart.SeriesCollection.Count
    
    For I = 1 To xSCount
        With xChart.SeriesCollection(I)
            J = 1
            Set xRg = ActiveSheet.Range(Split(Split(.Formula, ",")(2), "!")(1))
          
            For Each xCell In xRg
                ix = xCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
                If ix >= 1 Then
                   .Points(J).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(ix)
                   .Points(J).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(ix)
                End If
                J = J + 1
            Next
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I have looked at the amendments you provided and the information that another user gave to get rid of error messages however I still believe that the code is not looking in the right area as it needs to pull from worksheet 2 not the worksheet that it is on.
I am going to do some reading on it tonight to see if I can fix it - If you have any guides that I could use or you think are useful to help me learn that would be amazing

Comment: @jackLewis I would replace the `ActiveSheet` with the specific sheet ie `Sheets("Sheet 2")` or whatever the name is.